# Proactive message reminder in channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm having a requirement in a Teams bot where bot will send a reminder message provocatively if there is no response on a message thread for 5 days.
How i can achieve this. i'm using bot framework v3 (c#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send a [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages) you need to save user’s information in your backend storage. You can now use this information to send [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages#obtain-necessary-user-information) even using Postman/Fiddler.  You could have simple Web Service which triggers proactive message or it can be done via [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function).

Here is App Template for [Company Communicator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-company-communicator-app/wiki/Solution-overview) which uses Azure Function to send proactive message.